# Обновление данных после возврата из контроллера

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

Как правильно прописать логику в Swift,

В моем первом контроллере есть объект, например строка `string "Hello"`.

Мне надо перейти в новый контроллер, сразу прописать в него данные, из предыдущего контроллера `string "Hello"`.

В новом контроллере изменить этот строковой параметр например на `string "New Hello"`.

После чего вернуться в старый контроллер и обновить там первоначальную строку.

p/s В objective c это легко можно было реализовать блоками, теоретически в Swift можно сделать это-же клоужерами, но может есть какой-то более правильный способ ?

p/s storyboard в приложении не используется. Реализация через xib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании `segue`, это будет выглядеть так:

```
class VC1: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Private Instance Attributes
    private var stringAttr: String? = "Hello"


    // MARK: - Navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let identifier = segue.identifier else { return }
        switch identifier {
        case "GoToVC2":
            guard let viewController = segue.destination as? VC2 else { break }
            viewController.stringAttr = stringAttr
            viewController.stringAttrChangedClosure = { [weak self] (newString) in
                guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
                strongSelf.stringAttr = newString
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

class VC2: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Public Instance Attributes
    var stringAttr: String? = "Hello" {
        didSet {
            stringAttrChangedClosure?(stringAttr)
        }
    }
    var stringAttrChangedClosure: ((_ newString: String?) -> Void)?
}
```

Хочу обратить внимание что в `prepare(for:segue)` нельзя обращаться к элементам формы (IBOutlet), так как на этот момент они еще не инициализированы, поэтому для хранения данных необходимо будет создать временную переменную (`stringAttr` в данном примере). Т.е. строка 'viewController.someLabel.test = stringAttr' вызовет ошибку выполнения, в том случае если `someLabel` - это `@IBOutlet`.

Также для изменения данных в "передающей" стороне (VC1) в примере всегда необходимо использовать "блоки".

Comment: Прошу прощения что не написал, я не использую storyboard.

Comment: В таком случае вместо `prepare(for segue:` используйте ту функцию, в которой создается и отображается новый контроллер.